# Browser doesn't download the correct responsive image

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, responsive-images

```
<img :src="project.thumbnails.small[0]" 
         class="card-img-top"
         :srcset="`${project.thumbnails.small[0]} 300w, ${project.thumbnails.medium[0]} 900w, ${project.thumbnails.high[0]} 1400w`"
         sizes="(min-width: 300px) 90vw, (min-width: 768px) 20vw, (min-width: 991px) 10vw" 
         width="100%"
         :alt="project.title">
```

When the viewport is greater than 991px, the width of image is only 10% of the viewport; therefore the browser is supposed to get the 900w or 300w image, but instead it downloads the 1400w one. What am I doing wrong here?

This is the code rendered in the browser.

```
<img data-v-5857f165="" src="http://placehold.it/330x330" 
 srcset="http://placehold.it/330x330 300w, http://placehold.it/900x900 900w, http://placehold.it/1400x1400 1400w" 
 sizes="(min-width: 300px) 90vw, (min-width: 768px) 20vw, (min-width: 991px) 10vw" 
 width="100%" alt="sit amet" class="card-img-top">
```

I am using Chrome Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit) if that's relevant.

Comment: Not familiar with srcset, but are those backticks supposed to be there? What does the resulting HTML look like in the inspector?

Comment: @ceejayoz thats a javascript template literal. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: @BertEvans I'm not sure how well that's going to work with the `:` in `:srcset`, which does something similar if I'm reading it right.

Comment: @ceejayoz It should be fine. v-bind just means it will bind the result of the javascript expression. A template literal is just another expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have solved the problem.

Chrome shows high quality images if they are in the cache. Why download additional lower quality images if they already have higher quality images in the pocket, right? See [this article](https://ryanbenhase.com/responsive-images-not-working/).

Next, modify the order of media queries in sizes, from high to low:

```
<img :src="project.thumbnails.small[0]" 
         class="card-img-top"
         :srcset="`${project.thumbnails.small[0]} 300w, ${project.thumbnails.medium[0]} 900w, ${project.thumbnails.high[0]} 1400w`"
         sizes="(min-width: 991px) 10vw, (min-width: 768px) 20vw, 300px" 
         width="100%"
         :alt="project.title">
```